# Best suggested DocuSign setup

Tags: docusignapi

I have an ASP, vb.net, forms-based system.  I want to allow people to use PDF documents created within that system to send them to DocuSign and out to others for signature.  I have used the DocuSign SDK to build a system that works; however, I am concerned that I may not have the best setup for that.

The problem relates to the "open" nature of this system.  Our users are allowed to see and modify all parts of the underlying system, including forms, coding, etc.  As a result, a clientID and secret would be seeable to users.  And that is concerning.

The system will need to be set to be easily used by our users.  So, having users set up a developer account, setting up API settings, etc., will not be something we can reasonably expect.

It would be better if the system did all the interaction and they just had to log on to DocuSign to send the document out for signing.  DocuSign has suggested becoming a partner in their referral system.  I worry that will still require all the pieces (clientID and secret) that people will be able to see.  But, I am not sure that is true.

Will being a partner mean we can avoid having those items saved in an open system where users can see them?  Or does being a partner mean some of that is removed or not necessary?

Is there a better way of setting this up so that we can avoid all that mess?

Comment: why not talk with the vendor? this is not a programming question

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason that all your customers wouldn't be able to use the same clientID (also know as Integration Key or IK) and secret key (clientSecret).

You will be the only one that can see/set them as the ISV. They will all use their own DocuSign accounts, using your IK. That is abosltuly fine and does not have any limitations.

We recommend ISVs use a single IK per app if it's the same code for the app even if they have multiple customers using the app.

Comment: So, the customers being able to clearly see the IK and secret isn't a security concern?  That would seem like a problem to me.  And, would I be in the partner program?  Or what background setup would I need?  DocuSign does not make it clear on how things work together relating to accounts, etc.  I've noticed several others in my same position asking the same types of questions.

Comment: The customers would NOT be able to see the secret.

Comment: Forgive me if I am being dense.  If the system is "open", so they can see all coding and the like and the secret key has to be used, wouldn't they be able to see it?

Comment: The secret key is on a server, the customers would not have access to this server.

Comment: "Open" system doesn't mean that customers have credentials to log into the server where the code is running.

Comment: But, that's what I mean.  The system is "open" for our users to go in and be able to see the coding and forms and modify them as they wish on the server.

Comment: Well, then a user can just delete the entire server and take over it to mine bitcoin. That's much worse than seeing the secret key.